# Proper use of close() and = null for Closable objects

Tags: java

Say, I'm using connection to database named `con` (or socket or anything else which is `Closable`). What happens after `close()`? Does `con` become equal to `null` or there is still something in it? And what is the difference between `con.close()` and `con = null`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `close`, the object should free all the resources it uses behind the scenes. In case of an instance of `java.sql.Connection`, it will one of two things:

- Free any physical connection to the database, thus freeing resources. This happens when you open a database connection manually e.g. `DriverManager.getConnection(...)`.
- Go into a SLEEPING state and wait to be invoked again. This happens when the `Connection` is handled by a `DataSource` which is handled by a database connection pool.

Setting the object `con = null` just assigns `null` value to a variable, the reference will still be alive until the Garbage Collector decides to remove it. Still, setting the `Connection` to `null` **doesn't** call `close` method, thus you can have memory leaks.

As a best practice, you should **ALWAYS** call `close` method on instances of `Closeable` or use `try-with-resources` (available since Java 7) to make sure the resource(s) is(are) always closed.

Comment: (Setting variables to null is really almost never necessary, FWIW.)